# SWF files not loaded on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flash

The swf files are not loaded on IE.IS there any settings that needs to be changed on IE

```
 <div>
 <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;">
 <tr>
 <td width="20%">
 <object width="100" height="100" id="microphone">
 <embed src="/media/players/game.swf" width="250" height="250" type='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
 </embed>
 </object>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the official syntax for embedding a Flash movie?

See [OBJECT and EMBED syntax](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html) in Adobe's knowledge base for a full example.

```
 <OBJECT 
  classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
  codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" 
  WIDTH="550" 
  HEIGHT="400" 
  id="myMovieName">

<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="myFlashMovie.swf">
<PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
<PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#FFFFFF>

<EMBED 
   href="/support/flash/ts/documents/myFlashMovie.swf" 
   quality=high 
   bgcolor=#FFFFFF 
   WIDTH="550" HEIGHT="400" NAME="myMovieName" 
   ALIGN="" 
   TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"
   PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

(Line breaks added for clarity)

Comment: Canu take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562124/embeded-swf-not-working-on-ie

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change any settings in IE. Which IE version you were testing?

I would recommend you to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed the flash(swf), its free. Give it a try :)

EDIT:

Oh, just a remainder. Make sure your path-to-swf is correct :)

Comment: SWFObject will save you lots of time and effort.  Use it.

Answer (score 0):

IE has trouble with SWF files. Try this code, which works for me. Replace X and Y with width and height and [SOURCE SWF] with source file.

```
<!--[if IE]> 
<object width="X" height="Y" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="[SOURCE SWF]" name="Web" style="width: Xpx; height: Ypx;" id="flash"> 
<param name="movie" value="[SOURCE SWF]"> 
<param name="quality" value="high"> <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"> 
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"> 
<!--[endif]-->
```

Then put this right below for non-IE browers:

```
<!--[if !IE]> --> 
<object width="X" height="Y" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/
pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
<param name="SRC" value="bookmark.swf">
<embed src="[SOURCE SWF]" height="X" width="Y"> </object>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```